# Does a complex lattice determine the vectors it is generated by?

Tags: complex-numbers, integer-lattices

A lattice $\Lambda$ in the complex plane is defined as $$\Lambda=\{n\omega_1+m\omega_2:(n,m)\in {\mathbb Z}^2\}$$
where $\omega_1$, $\omega_2$ are complex numbers that are ${\mathbb R}$- linearly independent (this means that $\omega_1\neq 0 \neq \omega_2$ and $\omega_1/\omega_2 \not \in {\mathbb R}$).
Is it true that $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ are determined by the lattice, up to a negative sign, meaning that if
$$\{n\omega_1+m\omega_2:(n,m)\in {\mathbb Z}^2\}=\{n\omega_1'+m\omega_2':(n,m)\in {\mathbb Z}^2\}$$
then $\{\omega_1',\omega_2'\}=\{\pm \omega_1, \pm \omega_2\}$?
I have looked at various sources where they discuss lattices in the complex plane, but I could not find a discussion about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $\omega_1=1$ and $\omega_2=i+1$. It is easy to see that this lattice is the same as the lattice generated by $\omega_1'=1$ and $\omega_2'=i$

Comment: Thanks, I now understand what is going on: $\omega=(\omega_1,\omega_2)$ will generate the same lattice as $\omega'=(\omega_1',\omega_2')$ exactly when there is a matrix $A\in \mbox{SL}(2,{\mathbb Z})$ so that $\omega'=A\omega$.

Comment: @Math101 I think you just want $\operatorname{GL}(2,\Bbb Z)$ since negative determinants should be allowed. This happens for $\omega_1=1$, $\omega_2=i$, $\omega_1'=1+i$, $\omega_2'=1$. Or maybe it's better to write $\operatorname{O}(2,\Bbb Z)$ to emphasize the determinant must be $\pm 1$. I'm pretty sure thats implied anyway in $\operatorname{GL}(2,\Bbb Z)$, but it's easy to mistake $\operatorname{GL}(2,\Bbb Z)$ to mean matrices with nonzero determinant.